# Regular Expression For Email With Apostrophe

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am building an **MVC 4 web application** and using **Fluent Validation** when validating some of my ViewModels.

I need to **validate Email addresses** and I was using this **regular expression**, it's the default one that comes in the AccountModels class when you create a default MVC application in Visual Studio

```
RuleFor(x => x.ConfirmEmail)
.Matches(@"^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*?\.[a-z]{2,6}|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(:\d{4})?$")
.WithMessage("Please enter a valid email address");
```

However, my client has told me this is not accepting email addresses which include apostrophes before the @ sign.

I am not good with regular expressions at all, so could someone please help me to amend this reg expressive to allow for apostrophes before the @ sign?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I had put in the wrong code sample, please see the regular expression now - this is the one that does not accept apostrophes.

Comment: Looks like it should match even with apostrophe. Can you provide the non matching email (perhaps change the domain name in it, and a few letters, for privacy). I suspect there might be another problem.

Comment: I agree, it clearly accepts them: `^([\w-\.']+)@` you can see the apostrophe in the character class... Oh and btw, you don't need to escape the dot inside the character class.

Comment: Pretty please, don't use regex to validate email addresses. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address and a large number of related questions.

Comment: Also, this regex is wacky. It will fail on top-level domains longer than six characters (there are several now) and what's with the literal IP address with exactly a four-digit port number? Even without the port number nonsense, it's wrong.

Comment: **Don't roll your own solution to this problem.**  If ever there is a programming problem where it makes sense to rely on existing code that has been written, tested and debugged, this is it.

Comment: For the record, if you have to have an email address with a literal IP address, the correct format is with brackets; `you@[10.9.87.6]`. There is no support for port numbers, with IP addresses or otherwise. (I see now that I misread the grouping for the port number; the regex will accept `you@example.com:1234` also.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After your update, the regular expression you are looking for is:

```
^[\w-']+(\.[\w-']+)*@([a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*?\.[a-z]{2,6}|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(:\d{4})?$
```

Note, the only thing changed here, is that the `'` (apostrophe) character has been added in each of the two character classes before the `@` symbol.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the user enters a completely uppercase email address. Though it's not a great use case to do this, it is something that people do - and the regex should support it.

Comment: @CSharpForEverMore - There are **many** forms of [valid e-mail address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses) that are not supported by this, such as: `"pretty \"strange\" address"@[IPv6:2001:db8:1ff::a0b:dbd0]`.   My goal was just to add enough to handle the very specific issue stated in the question.